# How to Inject Work Manager in ViewModel using Hilt

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I am trying to use Work manager in viewModel for uploading files on server, so how can i inject WorkManager?

I tried this https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack

but its seems uncompleted and `HiltWorkerFactory` not found

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

@Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() = Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
        .build()

}
```

Comment: You'd use `HiltWorkerFactory` for injecting classes into `Worker` instances. That has nothing to do with injecting dependencies into a ViewModel. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ ianhanniballake i added app code and HiltWorkerFactory inject this also , u can see code

Comment: i want use WorkManager instance in viewmodel how can i use it

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like below

Add provide method in your module

```
  @Provides
    fun provideWorkManager(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ) = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
```

Pass in your viewmodel as below

@HiltViewModel

```
class ViewModelDemo @Inject constructor(val workManager: WorkManager)
```

above code works for me,hope it helps you:)

Comment: If you are doing any custom config of the workManager, probably want to do that in module too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can inject Work Manager into your View Model. What you can do is enqueue a work request of your WorkManager inside your View Model.

```
// Example from the documentation
val myWork: WorkRequest = // ... OneTime or PeriodicWork
WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext()).enqueue(myWork)
```

Regarding the code snippet of the Application class that you included in your question, I would say make sure you included the required dependencies.

Comment: This is about using WorkManager with hilt

Comment: Good luck testing with ViewModel.